# Dygraphs panEnd callback

Tags: dygraphs

I'm looking for a way to attach a function on pan end, like zoomCallback. 
I'm writing an app in plain JS but I can't find a way to properly detect 
the end of panning. What I've tried:

- Found an example on replacing the pan handler [here](https://github.com/kaliatech/dygraphs-dynamiczooming-example/blob/master/j/JGS.Demo3Page.js#L169), but that doesn't work for me, Dygraph.Interaction = undefined.
- If I add { endPan: function() {...} } to Dygraph.defaultInteractionModel, that function is never called.
- Here's another example by adding endPan to the Dygraph function [here](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/issues/850), but that doesn't work either.
- Attached a mouseup/touchend event, but dateWindow_ is only updated after mouseup/touchend.

Reading through the comments in [dygraph.js](http://dygraphs.com/2.0.0/dygraph.js), it used to be possible to set a function on panEnd (line 2861), but that code is commented with "old ways of accessing these methods/properties", but doesn't say what the new way is. I've experimented with drawCallback, but walking the dygraph object doesn't reveal any variable that exposes if the user is still busy panning or not.

Is there a way to execute code on pan end?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can set your own interactionModel (I did it for zooming), but panning also works.

```
const myInteractions = Object.assign({}, Dygraph.defaultInteractionModel, {
      dblclick: (event, g, context) => {
        console.log("double-click!", event, g, context);
      },
      mousedown: (event, g, context) => {
        console.log("start mousedown");
        context.initializeMouseDown(event, g, context);
        Dygraph.startPan(event, g, context);
      },
      mousemove: (event, g, context) => {
        if(context.isPanning) {
          console.log("mouse is moving", event, g, context);
          Dygraph.movePan(event, g, context);
        }
      },
      mouseup: (event, g, context) => {
        console.log("mouseup", event, g, context);
        Dygraph.endPan(event, g, context);
        context.isPanning = false;
      }
});
```

within your chart init: add your `myInteractions` to the options

```
{
  // other options
  interactionModel: myInteractions,
}
```

Within the mouse-down event, you can check different keys to start e.g. zoom or pan

```
if (event.altKey || event.shiftKey) {
  Dygraph.startZoom(event, g, context);
} else {
  Dygraph.startPan(event, g, context);
}
```

Comment: Property 'startPan' does not exist on type 'typeof Dygraph'

Comment: Hmm, but it should ->  https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/blob/da2a028fc41e5573868358b3d9eda9826211d217/src/dygraph.js#L3464